# Passing command-line arguments/parameters to AutoIt executables

Tags: selenium-webdriver, autoit

My AutoIt script:

```
WinWaitActive("User Authentication","","10")

If WinExists("User Authentication") Then

   ; Enter a username.
   Send("prabu{TAB}")
   Send("{TAB}")

   ;Enter a Password.
   Send("Password")
   Send("{TAB}")
   Send("{SPACE}")

   ;Press Authenticate button.
   Send("{TAB} {ENTER}")

EndIf
```

- It waits for an authentication popup window to gain focus,
- enters a username and password,
- then presses the "Authenticate" button.

I "compiled" it to an .exe file and execute it from Selenium using:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\\Users\\Prabu\\Documents\\ds.exe");
```

But I want it to enter a different username and password every time. I intend to provide these to the script using command-line arguments (parameters if you will).

Is it possible to pass arguments/parameters to AutoIt scripts? If so, how should this be done and how do I access arguments/parameters provided to my script?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Changes to AutoIt script:

```
$username = $CmdLine[1]
$password=$CmdLine[2]
Send($username)
Send($password)
```

In Java :

```
String command="C:\\Users\\Prabu\\Documents\\ds.exe \"username1\" \"password1\"";      
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
```

Reference:

https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/intro/running.htm#CommandLine
http://seleniumocean.blogspot.in/2014/11/its-time-for-autoit-parameterizing.html